# How can i create a matrix from user's input in dialog box using tkinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have a 19x5 matrix that's by default only zeros. I want to create a window using tkinter that displays an empty 19x5 matrix that the user will fill with values (positive real) or leave blank. In that case i want blank inputs to remain zero and input values to replace the zeros in the respective place and the new matrix is saved.

```
import numpy as np
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from tkinter import *

demand = np.zeros((19,5))
```

Comment: what did you try? `tkinter` has widget `Entry()` to get text, and you could use it with layout manager `.grid(row, column)` to create matrix with many `Entry()`. You can use two `for`-loops to put widgets in rows and columns. But you can do it in standard window - `tkinter.Tk()` - not in dialog box. And you will have to add all code which get values from all `Entry()` and convert to numpy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` has `Entry()` to get text, and you can use it with layout manager `.grid(row, column)` to create `matrix`/`table` with many `Entry()`. You can use two `for-`loops to put widgets in rows and columns.

But you can do it in standard window - `tkinter.Tk()` - not in dialog box.

You have to add code which gets values from all `Entry()` and put in numpy array.   It is better to assign this code to `Button()`.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def get_data():
    for r, row in enumerate(all_entries):
        for c, entry in enumerate(row):
            text = entry.get()
            demand[r,c] = float(text)
        
    print(demand)
    
# --- main ---

rows = 19
cols = 5

demand = np.zeros((rows, cols))

window = tk.Tk()

all_entries = []
for r in range(rows):
    entries_row = []
    for c in range(cols):
        e = tk.Entry(window, width=5)  # 5 chars
        e.insert('end', 0)
        e.grid(row=r, column=c)
        entries_row.append(e)
    all_entries.append(entries_row)
        
b = tk.Button(window, text='GET DATA', command=get_data)
b.grid(row=rows+1, column=0, columnspan=cols)

window.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could also use `Label` to add numbers for rows and cols

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def get_data():
    for r, row in enumerate(all_entries):
        for c, entry in enumerate(row):
            text = entry.get()
            demand[r,c] = float(text)
        
    print(demand)
    
# --- main ---

rows = 19
cols = 5

demand = np.zeros((rows, cols))

window = tk.Tk()

for c in range(cols):
    l = tk.Label(window, text=str(c))
    l.grid(row=0, column=c+1)

all_entries = []
for r in range(rows):
    entries_row = []
    l = tk.Label(window, text=str(r+1))
    l.grid(row=r+1, column=0)
    for c in range(cols):
        e = tk.Entry(window, width=5)  # 5 chars
        e.insert('end', 0)
        e.grid(row=r+1, column=c+1)
        entries_row.append(e)
    all_entries.append(entries_row)
        
b = tk.Button(window, text='GET DATA', command=get_data)
b.grid(row=rows+1, column=0, columnspan=cols)

window.mainloop()
```

---

If you want something more complex (with more functions) then you could use `pandastable` which you can see in [DataExplorer](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataexplore.html)

More in my post on blog: [Tkinter PandasTable Examples](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-pandastable-examples-gb.html)

---

**BTW:** [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)